# iOS: Is it possible not to have launch image when launching app using custom url scheme?

Tags: ios

I understand it comes for the first launch but when application is already opened in the background and i try to open it again using custom url it shows launch image.

So every time i launch the app using custom url scheme it gives Launch Image.

Answer (score 1):

> So every time i launch the app using custom url scheme it gives Launch Image

Not so. Your app has been killed in the background (probably by you) and is therefore launching from a dead start. That is why the initial launch image is (rightly) being shown. The fault lies with your testing procedure.

You know this because when your app goes into the background, the system takes a "snapshot" and uses that as the launch image when the app comes back into the foreground. But you are not seeing that snapshot. That is because it is thrown away when the app is killed in the background.

Comment: Application is not getting killed in the background. I am using 2 way communication between apps using custom url scheme. My first App has few navigation and after that it takes data using custom url from second app. Second app send the data back to First app using custom URL. So if the application would have been killed , it will never redirect me to where i was left in the first app.

Comment: Did you provide a custom launch image for this scheme? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW15

Comment: No i am not using any custom launch image